# Pressing enter clicks button again

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this button that I click to print a document. but the issues is it stays in focus I think and if I press enter key by mistake it prints it again {basically the button is getting pressed again on enter key. I am already using e.preventDefault() so I don't know why it is doing it. Is it possible to remopve this behaviour?

Basically I only want handleOrderPrint() to run on click and not when Enter key is pressed.

```
<Button onClick={e => handleOrderPrint(e)} type="primary">Print</Button>}
```

```
 const handleOrderPrint = (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    ipcRenderer.send('generatePickingDocs', order);
    setPrinted(true);
  };
```

Edit---------------->
Already tried this:

```
const btnEl = React.useRef(null);
  const handleOrderPrint = (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.keyCode !== 13) {
      console.log("Keycode", e.keyCode);
      ipcRenderer.send('generatePickingDocs', order);
      setPrinted(true);
    }
  };
```

```
<Button ref={btnEl} onClick={e => handleOrderPrint(e)} type="primary">Print</Button>
```

Comment: Maybe you should disable the button in its event handler, or move the focus to another control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `onKeyPress` handler and check if <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is pressed.
Use [`Event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).

```js
const { useRef, useEffect } = React;

const App = (props) => {
  const ref = useRef();

  // set focus to button for testing
  useEffect(() => ref.current.focus(), []);

  const print = msg => console.log(msg);

  const handleClick = e => print('Printing...');

  const handleKeyPress = e => {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
      e.preventDefault();
      return;
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        ref={ref}
        onKeyPress={handleKeyPress}
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
        Print
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Still going through when enter is pressed

Comment: Updated. Using `preventDefault()`.

Comment: Still the same issue, for some reason when you press enter on a button it triggers a click event, when you console.log(e.key) it will give you undefined.

Comment: Have you run the snippet? pressing `Enter` won't show "Printing...". The code uses `onKeyPress`. Clicking however shows "Printing..."

Comment: I get error on the line 
``` 
 useEffect(() => ref.current.focus(), []);
```
Cannot read property 'focus' of undefined

Comment: @Jaykch, there's a `ref` attached to button and in the code it is also using `useRef()` to initialize `ref`.

Comment: Actually it wasn't that, I was using a ternary operator to switch between grey and primary colour buttons and didn't set the ref on the other button so it was giving me the error, it works. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Jaykch good to know you've solved your other error. glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use `printed` as button disable trigger

```
 const [printed, setPrinted] = React.useState(false); 
 const handleOrderPrint = (e: any) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        ipcRenderer.send('generatePickingDocs', order);
        setPrinted(true);
      };
 return (
 <Button disabled={printed} onClick={e => handleOrderPrint(e)} type="primary">Print</Button>)
```

**Edited**

How about using `ref`

```
 const [printed, setPrinted] = React.useState(false); 
 const btnEl = React.useRef(null);
 const handleOrderPrint = (e: any) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        btnEl.blur();
        ipcRenderer.send('generatePickingDocs', order);
        setPrinted(true);
      };
 return (
 <Button ref={btnEl} onClick={e => handleOrderPrint(e)} type="primary">Print</Button>)
```

Comment: I need the ability to print again.

Comment: Nope, still goes through. The button is still in focus so maybe I need to remove the focus after a second or something